# Subspace over a line in a plane

Tags: general-topology

Consider a line $L$ over a plane.Describe the topology $L$ inherits as a subspace of the followings.

1. $\mathbb{R}_k \times \mathbb{R}_k$ where $\mathbb{R}_k$ is $K$-topology on $\mathbb{R}$.
2. $(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R})_d$ where is dictionary order topology over $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$.

Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Do you mean that $L$ is a line **in** the plane? And in (2) do you mean the dictionary order topology on $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$? We don’t normally think of $\Bbb R$ itself as having a dictionary order topology. (And if we did, it would be the ordinary Euclidean topology.)

Comment: L is a line in plane. Please explain a little about your comment on 2.

Comment: I don’t know what you mean by $\Bbb R_d$, because we don’t normally talk about a dictionary order on a space that is not a product. I suspect that you mean $(\Bbb R\times\Bbb R)_d$, the dictionary order topology on $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$, but that’s not what you wrote.

Comment: Yes Sir , it is $(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R})_d$.

Comment: In both problems it depends on the specific line. The second problem is much easier than the first: there are only two cases. The first has several cases, and two of the resulting topologies are unfamiliar. Are you sure that the problem does not say anything about *which* line(s) you’re to consider?

Comment: No Sir. Actually this is my own idea. I was trying to generalise a problem of Munkresh Page 92. It was the same question on the spaces $\mathbb{R}_l \times \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}_l \times \mathbb{R}_l$.

Comment: Ah, okay. I’ll give you some hints for both problems, but the first one really does get a bit difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases it depends on the line $L$. The first problem is much harder than the second, so I’d look at the second problem first.

In preparation, note that the topology on $\Bbb R_k$ is the same as the usual topology on $\Bbb R$ **except** at $0$. If $x\in\Bbb R$ and $A\subseteq\Bbb R$, and if $x\ne 0$, then $x$ is a limit point of $A$ in the Euclidean topology if and only if $x$ is a limit point of $A$ in the $K$-topology. $0$ is different: $0$ is a limit point of $K$ in the Euclidean topology, but not in the $K$-topology. I’ll call $0$ a *special point* of $L$.

1. If $L$ is parallel to the $y$-axis, show that $\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto y$ is a homeomorphism and conclude that $L$ is homeomorphic to $R_k$. If $L$ is parallel to the $x$-axis, or if $L$ passes through the origin but is not vertical, show that $\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto x$ is a homeomorphism and conclude that $L$ is homeomorphic to $R_k$. Finally, if $L$ is not parallel to either axis and does not pass through the origin, then $L$ has an $x$-intercept and a $y$-intercept, and they are distinct points. This is the hardest case: in its relative topology $L$ has two special points, the two intercepts, rather than just one, so it’s not homeomorphic to $\Bbb R_k$. Moreover, the $K$-like set that make the $y$-intercept special is always on the right of the intercept, but the $K$-like set that make the $x$-intercept special can be on either side of the intercept, depending on whether the slope of $L$ is positive or negative.
2. If $L$ is not parallel to the $y$-axis, you can use the fact that for any $p=\langle x,y\rangle\in\Bbb R^2$, the set $\{x\}\times(y-1,y+1)$ is an open nbhd of $p$ in the dictionary order topology on $\Bbb R^2$ to show that $L$ has a very simple topology. If $L$ is parallel to the $y$-axis, show that it’s homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$ with the usual Euclidean topology.